# Averaging across list of multiple keys in Pymongo and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a list of keys, which I want to match with keys at the level of a document and perform an average of that quantity associated with keys. So the average runs across all the keys. Such that [key1, key2, key3] will effectively be an average over all keys.

I have something like this:

```
for key in listFields:
  query[key] = { "$exists": True }
  average[key] = { "$avg": "$"+key}

pipeline = [{"$group": {"_id": None, "average": average } }]

results = db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

However this fails:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: The field 'average' must be an accumulator object
```

What is the most reliable way to do this?

Comment: Can you please explain the problem with an example.

Comment: It would be very useful to provide the exact code instead of a code approach, as you provide a specific error, and a few sample data.